# SWT: Changing the background color of a label two times

Tags: swt, runnable

My problem is to change a background color in a runnable. I am trying to change the background color of a label like traffic lights do (red -> yellow -> green) and I have not much experience with SWT. So I do not see why my attempt doesn't work:

```java
Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
    public void run()
    {
     label.setBackground(red);
     try {
         Thread.sleep(1000);
     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
       }

     label.setBackground(yellow);    
     try {
         Thread.sleep(1000);
     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
       }

     label.setBackground(green);

     }
    });
```

What happens is that nothing is changing during the waiting time (2*1 second) and the last color (in this case green) is shown - no red and no yellow. Could you please give me a hint what my mistake is? Or an idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Display.asyncExec` runs the entire `Runnable` in the User Interface thread. So your two `Thread.sleep` calls run in the UI thread and stop the thread from updating the UI.

To do something with a delay use the `timerExec` method of `Display` to schedule a `Runnable` to run after a delay.

```java
// Set first color. Note: use `asyncExec` if you are not in the UI thread

label.setBackground(red);

// Schedule changes

Display.getDefault().timerExec(1000, new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
      if (!label.isDisposed()) {
        label.setBackground(yellow);
      }
    }
});

Display.getDefault().timerExec(2000, new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
      if (!label.isDisposed()) {
        label.setBackground(green);
      }
    }
});
```